# log4j API to log errors

Tags: java, log4j

I am running REST web service on Tomacat 6.0.32. I  am using log4j API to log errors or anything else.
 Basically you only need to include this line of code

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestLogging.class.getName());
logger.debug("String blah blah");
```

I run main method to test if it is working. So, the program writes log info into text file and on the console of NetBeans.
But if you deploy the project and then run it on the browser those logs do not appear no where; neither on console nor text file nor on Tomcat's logs.

The following is properties file:

```
# Set root category priority to DEBUG and set its only appender to A1
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, A1, file
log4j.additivity.logger=false

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender (writes to system console).
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%p [%t] %F %L %x - %m%n

#### Second appender writes to a file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=eMart_logger.log

# Control the maximum log file size
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
# Archive log files (one backup file here)
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %d %t %F %L - %m%n
```

What is the problem?
Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by "run it on the browser"? Is it an applet?

Comment: You will most likely need to post your log4j configuration file in order to receive any help

Comment: you need to add the ConsoleAppender as one of the root loggers to get log messages in your console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a FileAppender to get it to log to a file when you are running on a server.
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html